# Best way to create isLoggedIn function in AngularJS that can be accessed in any controller or template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need an isLoggedIn() function that both controllers and templates all have access to (templates need it in order to do something like ng-show="isLoggedIn()"). What's the best way to do this?

If the answer is a service, then is it possible to access a service from within a template, or does each of my controllers need to create a wrapper function for the template to see it (in $scope)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually have a 'MainCtrl' in my body tag and put global stuff in it.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  ...
</body>

function MainCtrl($scope, authService) {
  $scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
    return authService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Then every other scope will inherit the isLoggedIn function.

You can also put the isLoggedIn on the $rootScope, but I like this way.

Comment: Ah neat, I didn't realize controllers could have sub-controllers like that. That works fine. I'll leave the question open for a day or two more in case anyone else comes along with a different best practice or anything, and otherwise mark this as accepted.

Comment: Same here.  I didn't know about sub-controllers.  Thanks this helped me clean up a few things I've been trying to figure out.